# Exporting AD users' attributes to CSV file from a text file with only IDs in powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm using PowerShell, and I'm trying to export AD users' attributes to a CSV file from a text file that contains only user IDs (`samAccountName`). The text file can contain any amount of user IDs.

The problem is that when I run the code I have, the file created only has 1 entry, and it's always the last user in the list of users in the text file, regardless of the amount of users I try to get the info for.

The code I run is this:

```
$Users = Get-Content "C:\IDs.txt" |
ForEach-Object {Get-ADUser -Identity $User -Properties * | Select Name,SamAccountName,Description,Title,DistinguishedName,Enabled | Export-Csv "c:\UserInfo.csv" -NoTypeInformation}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: yes, `| Export-Csv "c:\UserInfo.csv" -NoTypeInformation` should be outside the loop :)

Comment: Amazing! I guess after 9hrs of staring at a computer screen a simple mistake had me breaking my head. Thank you @SantiagoSquarzon it is working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following statement wouldn't work:

```
$Users = Get-Content "C:\IDs.txt" | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADUser -Identity $User -Properties * ....
```

Because `$User` is not defined, in a `ForEach-Object` loop, to refer to the current item from the pipeline, you should use [`$_` (`$PSItem`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_psitem?view=powershell-7.2).

As for the likable cause you get the last element in your export, you have previously defined `$User` while testing your code, then you're querying the same AD Object for each line in `C:\IDs.txt` and the export, since `Export-Csv` is inside the loop, is being overwritten over and over.

The steps to fix it are quite straight forward, just put `Export-Csv` as the last statement in your pipeline and change `$User` for `$_`:

```
$props = 'Name', 'SamAccountName', 'Description', 'Title', 'DistinguishedName', 'Enabled'
Get-Content "C:\IDs.txt" |
    ForEach-Object { Get-ADUser -Identity $_ -Properties $props } |
    Select-Object $props |
    Export-Csv "c:\UserInfo.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Also the assignment to `$Users` (`$Users = ...`) will be always null since the output from `Get-ADUser` is being directed to `Export-Csv`.

Lastly, since `Get-ADUser` can process identities from pipeline, no `ForEach-Object` is needed:

```
$props = 'Name', 'SamAccountName', 'Description', 'Title', 'DistinguishedName', 'Enabled'
Get-Content "C:\IDs.txt" | Get-ADUser -Properties $props |
    Select-Object $props |
    Export-Csv "c:\UserInfo.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```